# Marklogic sparql query default retrieval order

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

We are saving a tree structure in Marklogic database using semantics. We have created a custom predicate called "childof" and storing the children.

Java object:

```
public class HierarchyTree {

private String documentUri;

private List<HierarchyTree> children;

public String getDocumentUri() {
    return documentUri;
}

public void setDocumentUri(String documentUri) {
    this.documentUri = documentUri;
}

public List<HierarchyTree> getChildren() {
    return children;
}

public void setChildren(List<HierarchyTree> children) {
    this.children = children;
}
}
```

Tee structure is depicted below:

[image]

While saving the tree we are doing a depth first search and creating triple for each node as: 
**`<`documenturi`>` childof `<`documenturi`>`** and saving it in a collection.

With each iteration we add a new triple where child becomes parent of the next child till the bottom of the tree is reached and add it to the same collection.

The collection holds all triples for a particular hierarchy tree.

Now the problem is while retrieving the triple from the collection we are not able to control the order of the triples.

**1. What default order does Marklogic retrieve triples when we fire a SPARQL query?**

**2. Is there a way we can retrieve triples in the same order inserted or in reverse order?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no concept in MarkLogic of things like insert order, etc. Furthermore, when running SPARQL queries (like many optimised queries in MarkLogic), the original documents are not touched, but just the index holding the values. I don't think anything 'default' will help you here. It will likely be up to you to build more robust SPARQL queries based on the information in your triples or via additional hinformation via RDFs for inference.

These two documents may help:

https://developer.marklogic.com/features/semantics/path-examples

https://developer.marklogic.com/features/semantics/inference-examples

Comment: Thanks for your answer David. We coded this in the Java layer.  I have coded method to build the proper tree hierarchy no matter what order the triples are retrieved.

Comment: No Problem.  Please help keep StackOverflow useful. If the answer provided is correct, please mark it as so. Otherwise, please elaborate so that others may assist.